# Set Runtime Library of all projects in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I would like to set the runtime library of all projects in my Visual Studio 2017 solution at once. Currently they're all set to /MD, but I would like to compile the project as /MT. The solution I'm working on has something like 105 projects, so changing them by hand is tedious. Is there a way to do this automatically, or at least faster than opening up each project properties file individually?

Note that I cannot change the configuration. The project must be compiled as RelWithDebInfo.

Thank you.

Comment: You can select multiple projects - and opening properties should show the common entries for all selected projects allowing to change settings at once.  Another approach - Just use Find in Files from some text editor (like Notepad++) and edit the vcxproj files as text (which is xml) with something like Replace all...

Comment: Oh derp, I was selecting all targets at once (including stuff like ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK) so I wasn't getting any properties. Restricting my selection to just those with a Runtime Library configuration allowed me to set multiple at once. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - since this was the answer you are looking for:

You can select multiple projects - and opening properties should show the COMMON entries for all selected projects allowing to change settings at once.